# UIImage orientation changed when drawing in UIGraphicsBeginImageContext

Tags: objective-c, uiimage, image-resizing, uigraphicscontext

I want to resize the UIImage so I used below code.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
[sourceImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)];
UIImage *destImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Above code works fine but the orientation of destImage is changed. I don't know how.

```
source.imageOrientation = 3
destImage.imageOrientation = 0
```

Can any one tell me how to resize image with same orientation as sourceImage?

**Edited:**

```
UIImage *scaleImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:destImage.CGImage
                                scale:sourceImage.scale orientation:sourceImage.imageOrientation];
```

**Edited:**

I am getting [image: this] result after resize the image.

I have tried above code also. But still it give me opposite orientation.

Comment: Ekata try another solution

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UIImage orientation is changing when drawing in UIGraphicsBeginImageContext](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24283017/uiimage-orientation-is-changing-when-drawing-in-uigraphicsbeginimagecontext)

Comment: @fishinear I used that code but it didn't work, thats why I asked this question.

Comment: If you want people to help you, you need to do better than "it didn't work". It works fine for me. State explicitly in your question which code you have used, what you expect it to do, and what it did instead.

Comment: Another question: why do you want the `imageOrientation` property of the destination image to be the same as the original? The imageOrientation states how the image must be rotated during drawing, which is exactly what happens when you do drawInRect. So an imageOrientation of 0 for the destination is actually correct.

Comment: @fishinear Check my question I have updated. Image orientation is changed after resize when image is large. Got?

Comment: The image orientation is **not** changed after resize. Check my answer, I hope that will clarify it better to you.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to set the `orientationMode` for the destination image. The `orientationMode` is an indication how to rotate the image when drawing it. That is, the `UIImage` contains the original, unrotated, data (usually in `CGImage` format), and the `orientationMode` property. When drawing the `UIImage` (for example when adding it to a `UIImageView`), it will rotate it as well, as needed.

Your code is also drawing the image, and therefore will rotate it:

```
[sourceImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)];
UIImage *destImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
```

The `destImage` will contain the rotated original data, and `orientationMode` `UIImageOrientationUp`. The net result is, that drawing the `destImage` will result in the same image with the same orientation as the `sourceImage`.

The only difference comes when you actually use the `CGImage` original data from each (and therefore ignoring the `orientationMode` property), then the destination image will be a rotated version of the source. If you are going to work with the `CGImage` anyways, then it's better to use the `CGImage` level operations to resize the image, for example (this comes from http://fingertwister.tumblr.com/post/9074775714/code-to-create-a-resized-cgimage-from-a-cgimage, I did not verify it):

```
+ (CGImageRef)resizeCGImage:(CGImageRef)image toWidth:(int)width andHeight:(int)height {
    // create context, keeping original image properties
    CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGImageGetColorSpace(image);
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, width, height,
        CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(image),
        CGImageGetBytesPerRow(image),
        colorspace,
        CGImageGetAlphaInfo(image));
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorspace);

    if(context == NULL)
        return nil;

    // draw image to context (resizing it)
    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), image);
    // extract resulting image from context
    CGImageRef imgRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    CGContextRelease(context);

    return imgRef;
}
```

Comment: Ok Thanks. Let me try.

Answer (score -1):

Resize the imageView

```
CALayer *layer;
layer=self.view.layer;
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
CGContextClipToRect (UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),captureFrame); //Give your frame of image here(x,y,width,height)
[layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *screenImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Also try below code

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.frame.size);
[drawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 3.0);
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
CGContextFlush(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
drawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Let me try this solution.

Comment: Can you please explain me "captureFrame"? Need to pass frame of source image?

Comment: Yes pass it your source frame

Comment: Ok. But Are you sure that it resize the image? And hows should I know that the image has been resized properly?

Comment: Yeah I am sure it will resize your image